# Embedd contact card

Tags: html

I'm making a small portfolio/application site in wordpress. Since I'm not much for social I would like to embed a contact card, like one of those you send over sms/mms/textmessage etc.

- Is there some html syntax I could use or do I need to create a contact-card file?
- Is there differences between platforms (windows phone, android and ios)?

---

EDIT: I have a link that makes the users device call me.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by contact card?

Comment: In your phone you have contacts. These contacts have email, phone and adress info.

Comment: You can create simple table of information. Or do you want to send this "card" via email to someone?

Comment: I want the user to press a link that adds my contact info to his adress book.

Answer (score -1):

Dug up some standards for this, there seems to be a Contacts API that:

> enables access to a user's address book service from inside a Web application

http://www.w3.org/TR/contacts-api/

If you'd like to use that, or other alternatives, i found more useful info at [Add a contact to the mobile device Address book from an HTML webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669912/add-a-contact-to-the-mobile-device-address-book-from-an-html-webpage)

Comment: "Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation."