# Save contact from mobile web browser to phone directory

Tags: php

Is there any way to directly write into user's contact book from mobile web page  without using vcf method ?

Right now i am downloading vcf file from browser. but i want to save directly to phone book.

i am using PHP as backend.

Comment: there is no way you can interract with the user's phone with PHP. Even with javascript, you can do very few things from a web page. you have to use the vcs method

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669912/add-a-contact-to-the-mobile-device-address-book-from-an-html-webpage